# How to export a project in Visual Studio Team System

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, tfs, version-control

How can I export an entire Visual Studio project? I want to get a non-source-controlled copy on my local hard drive.

I come from a SVN background and I'm just getting into TFS...
In Tortoise SVN, I would use the export all command for this -- I would right-click the project directory and drag it to another directory and choose "Export all".

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs across this question - thinking of SVN's "Export" feature...

"Get latest" into a new/separate workspace seems to be the best solution that is built into TFS.
See this question:  [TFS Get Specific Version into separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597476/tfs-get-specific-version-into-separate-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the latest version of your project then do the same thing?  drag/drop your directory to another location on your drive?  You can also open the solution and choose File -> Change Source Control to disconnect it from source control in its current location.