# Export or Download Source Control to local folder for a given Change set ID

Tags: .net-4.5, team-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TFS Get Specific Version into separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597476/tfs-get-specific-version-into-separate-folder)

I have a change set ID and I want to download or export code from source control till the Change set Id. Can I use ''get this version'' or some other way to download the code to local folder without effect current work space  or version in Source control ?

TFS 2012 &
User have full rights on TFS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it an option for you to create a new Workspace referencing a different folder, switch to new workspace and perform a Get Specific Version that matches your changeset id?