# Can I copy(grab a copy) of the files of an ChangeSet in TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I need to manually deploy some files to server. Is there is a quick way to get the copies of the  files of an ChangeSet in TFS 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`getcs` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413280%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the [`tfpt` power tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).  This will get *only* the files that were included in a changeset.

This will allow you to, for example:

```
tfpt getcs /changeset:C1999
```

Comment: Is this will copy all change-set file, so that i can put in a folder?

Comment: @user960567: This will do a get of all the files that were modified as part of the changeset.  It will not get the respository as of the changeset, for that you would just do a `tf get`.  You can then put it in a folder.

Comment: I used this command to get a list of all the files in several change sets and then used a text editor to massage the header info in each file down to jujst the file path.  Then presto... I now have a list of the changed files, which I'll use to go through and apply a label.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I wanted to put the files "somewhere else" other than the workspace directory. The solution I found was in SO, of course: 
[TFS Get Specific Version into separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597476/tfs-get-specific-version-into-separate-folder)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Start and write "Developer powershell"
2. Start the application
3. Navigate to a folder within your workspace (cd %path%)
4. Define a list of changesets for example:

   *$myArray = 1028474,1028480,1028491*
5. Enter the following and press enter to execute:

   *foreach ($element in $myArray) { tfpt getcs /changeset:$element}*