# TFS source code explorer: browse specific revision

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, tfs, version-control

In SVN it is possible to use the 'repository browser' to browse an older revision of the trunk. That way you can see all folders and files belonging to this and previous revisions in the trunk.

When folders and files have been moved this would be convenient to find them, not only a specific changeset.

Is there a similar method to do this in the TFS source code explorer?
It seems I can only see the latest revision in the browser.

Comment: You can view the history of all branches as changesets, and click on the changesets to see the history of that branch. I'm not familiar with that SVN functionality, so let me know if this is close or not.

Comment: 'not only a specific changeset.' I'm aware of using changesets but thats not what I meant, I talked about the view in the TFS source code explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want to browse a specific revision without getting it. Like an online preview:

You go into the web portal and select Code. Then select the changeset, in changeset details, there is an option-- **Browse files**
[image]

After click it, you could  open source control explorer to browser the repository as of this version. For example I have selected *changeset69* and will show files in the repo as below:

[image]

*By the way, I'm using the latest **TFS2017update2** version, this feature seems only available with this version for now.*

---

To browse the version control folders of TFS in VS, select Menu **View**, **Other Windows** and then Source Control Explorer.

To include deleted folders and files for version control using Source Control Explorer, select **Tools**, **Source Control**, and ensure the **Show deleted items in Source Control Explorer** checkbox is selected under the Visual Studio Team Foundation Server node. You could also easily track the history/changeset for deleted files in TFS, just right click and select *view history*.
[image]

According to your description, seems you want to get all folders and files in the branch/trunk for an older revision. In TFS, you could  **Get Specific Version**  instead of get latest version of the branch. Details please refer this question: [TFS Get Specific Version into separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597476/tfs-get-specific-version-into-separate-folder)

How to do this in VS: right click the branch-**Advance**-Get Specific Version

Comment: To be specific: I want to browse a specific revision without getting it. Like an online preview. I think its not possible in TFS.

Comment: @Picard Got it, actually you could. Just need to select **Browse files** in a specific changeset. Then it will show  what you need, details please see my update answer.

Comment: Yes! This seems to be it. Sadly I do not have "Browse files" link in the changeset. But that will be a configuration I suppose.
You should add information where to start. I'm assuming you are starting via Web Browser in the TFS Web Pages.

Comment: @Picard Yes, through web portal - code -changeset- changeset details- browser files. By the way, I'm using the latest **TFS2017update2** version, this feature seems only available with this version for now.