# TFS: "Get This Version" vs "Rollback Entire Changeset"

Tags: tfs

I find myself needing to remote debug some deployed code, I have a clear changeset defined in tfs that is the code that was deployed.

**My question is**: What is the standard procedure in TFS to ensure my local code matches what has been deployed to live.

"*Get This Version*": I seem to recall that operation only checks out the changeset in question, leaving all other files in place, some of which have have been changed by another later changeset

"*Rollback Entire Changeset*": This one appears most promising, but I'm confused if it means 'Roll back TO this changeset', or if it means 'Roll back this changeset' effectively leaving the code in a state BEFORE that changeset was checked it.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, you shouldn't use **rollback entire changeset** feature. This will influence your source control in TFS. If you  roll back a file to an earlier version, tfs will eliminating the effect of all changesets that occurred after that version. More details please take a look at this tutorial: [Roll back changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/roll-back-changesets)

Actually you just want to get an older version in history include **all** files for a branch or root project folder.

In TFS, you could  **Get Specific Version**  instead of get latest version of the branch. Details please refer this question: [TFS Get Specific Version into separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597476/tfs-get-specific-version-into-separate-folder)

How to do this in VS: right click the branch-**Advance**-Get Specific Version.  Have a look at my answer in this similar question: [TFS source code explorer: browse specific revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942821/tfs-source-code-explorer-browse-specific-revision/45950883#45950883)